# checking if the file name is equals to other files cell value

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a master Excel file which has a variable Name.
My vba code can let me open another Excel file from masterFile.From this code

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
    .Title = "Bitte die neue Exceldatei(*.xls) für die Verknüpfungsaktualisierung auswählen"
    .ButtonName = "Auswählen"
    .InitialFileName = Worksheets("Vorgaben").Range("C8").Value & "*.xlsm"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show = 0 Then Exit Sub

    sPfad = VBA.CurDir
    vDatei = .SelectedItems(1)
    sExcelFile = Mid(vDatei, Len(sPfad) + 2)
End With

NeuerLink = vDatei
Workbooks.Open Filename:=NeuerLink

osman = Right(NeuerLink, Len(NeuerLink) - InStrRev(NeuerLink, "\"))
```

My question is ,when i open this new file the value in Cell F6 should be equal to value of my variable Name masterfile.
If that is true i would like to continue to my code, when Cell F6 has a different value, i would like to have a error message which sais "Error".

How can i do this ?

Comment: What is variable Name masterfile?

Comment: i can save it with different names, in my program the variable is called anan and anan includes some user Inputs, which already works fine. I only Need to check this variable anan sth like if anan= Worksheets.Range or sthr like that which i can not figure out

Answer (score 0):

Here is an If statement example that you can use with your code:

```
Sub IfExample()

    ' Here is where your existing code can go.

    If Cells(6, 6).Value <> anan Then
        MsgBox ("Error")
        GoTo ExitHere
    End If

    ' Here is where you can put the code that you want to continue to.


ExitHere:

End Sub
```

Comment: whats the value of I6 Then?

Comment: I have no idea what is in I6.  The if statement is based on this sentence from your problem description: "when i open this new file the value in Cell F6 should be equal to value of my variable Name masterfile".